# Why would ActiveRecord::Base.execute_query stop returning all the results after the 20th row?

Tags: ruby, oracle, activerecord

I'm working on a test suite that requires me to pull data out of an Oracle database. I was using a query that was already written since it would be easier than setting up all the activerecord objects. I'm not using rails and instead using gem activerecord 3.2.6.

I've found that of the 14 columns of data in the return suddenly, starting with the 21st row, only 12 of them actually have data. This query returns full data for rows past 20 when used in Oracle SQL Developer so I know it's not the query.

Could it be that I need to give it more time to finish returning all the data? This doesn't really seem likely since it's always the 21st row that first has the problem. Is it an issue with the fact that some of the data can be NULL and once it finds the first NULL activerecord screws up?

I really have no clue what to do here and the only thing I can think to try is to install different versions of activerecord and hope that one of them works properly.

Answer (score 0):

> **"This doesn't really seem likely since it's always the 21st row that first has the problem."** Is it an issue with the fact that some of the data can be NULL and once it finds the first NULL activerecord screws up?

Perhaps you can try making one of the rows < 21 (say row 8) have some NULL data and see if the query chokes there?

Comment: Well, if I rewrite the query so that it just reorders the data and runs into a NULL value there straight off then none of them have any data in the last two columns.

Comment: @ChrisAtkinson, hmm...I was trying to say give your query a different set of test data (rather than just rewriting the query to reorder) where the NULL data occurs before the 21st row, since that's where the NULL appears in the original test data set.  Then if you get 14 full data columns back even if row 8 had some null values, then you'll know it's not the fact that the query hit a NULL value that caused the problem.  There's something else going on with row 21 and your query.  I guess the idea is to just rule out possibilities.